# How to make TextInputLayout with red astrisk mark

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make mandatory field with the use of TextInputLayout. I used Spannable class but display the hint of TextInputLayout in single color.I want my view to look something like in below link.

https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-search-filter

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially read Why is [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following TextInputEditText to look as similar as possible to the Material Design Text Field.

XML Layout

```
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="25">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:inputType="text|textCapSentences"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/title"
                android:textColorHint="@color/transparent38"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Color

```
<color name="transparent38">#66000000</color>
```

Java

```
etlayout = (TextInputLayout)findviewbyid(R.id.etlayout);

        TextWatcher twTitle = new TextWatcher() { //Analyzes when the view changes
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (true) { //Replace condition with validity test
                etlayout.setErrorEnabled(false); //Removes the extra space
                etlayout.setError(null); //Removes the error message
            } else { //If the text is not valid
                etlayout.setErrorEnabled(true); //Makes the space for the error appear
                etlayout.setError("Invalid input"); //Shows a message
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        };
        etTitle.addTextChangedListener(twTitle);
```